# Finding a two-sided confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval

Let $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$ be i.i.d. $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, where $\sigma^2$ is known, but $\mu$ is unknown. Construct a two sided 95% CI for $\mu$ based on $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$?

I am unsure how to go about this problem when there is an unknown involved.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to speak of a confidence interval when there is _not_ an unknown involved.

Comment: First, pretend $n$ is 50 and $\sigma$ is 7. Figure out how to build the confidence interval from that. Then, go back and figure out what would be different if you had left the symbols in place all along. (Hint: very little would be different.)